# SSH connect to host port 22: Connection refused

Tags: debian, ssh

After I booted up my system today, I can't connect using ssh to a debian server.
Here is the result of running ssh with -vvv

```
ssh xxx@ssh.xxx.com -vvv
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ssh.xxx.com [ip] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ip port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ssh.xxx.com port 22: Connection refused
```

netstat

```
$sudo netstat -tulpen | grep ":22"

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          26630      2812/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          26632      2812/sshd
```

I also tried running ssh using a different port after adding it to ssh config to no avail.

The next thing I did is to try to ssh using putty in a windows vm but it also showed an error "Network error: connection refused"

Yesterday morning I was able to connect using ssh on the same machine and everything was normal.

I can ping the server normally, I can open rutorrent web-interface from my browser (rtorrent is installed on the server).

All the ports I'm trying to connect through are open.

I tried to ssh into a different server and it worked.

I guess the problem is on the server side, I don't have root access to the server, but multiple admins checked if my ip is being blacklisted or denied and it's not could there be anything leading to this.

I tried to connect using a browser-based web SSH client [console](http://www.serfish.com/console)
from the description:

from it's description

> It can be used to bypass firewalls and proxies on a secure HTTP
>   connection. Moreover, the consoleFISH makes it possible to anonymously
>   open SSH connections as the IP address of the connecting web client is
>   not sent to the remote system.

so it's definitely an IP issue, if my IP is not in a ban list (the server uses fail2ban), what other place might be refusing or blocking my IP on the server.

Comment: Have you tried the connection from other host? Checkout iptables also if the connection to port 22 is ACCEPTED from your IP address

Comment: I tried to connect to that specific server with the console web-based ssh client, and the connection went fine. I also tried to ssh into another server from my current machine using port 22 and connection also was ok.

Comment: If you can, try accepting the connection to port 22 from your ip with iptables $ iptables -A INPUT -s [your ip] -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Since you have connectivity to the server, this is almost certainly going to be a problem on the server side.  Possibilities include: firewalls, change in sshd config, sshd not running, etc.

Comment: @BrandonXavier If the problem is on the server side, why is the connection through the [web based client](http://www.serfish.com/console/) going through normally ?

Comment: Because the server is allowing ssh connections on its public interface.  That doesn't necessarily mean it's allowing an ssh connection on the interface you're hitting.  I suppose it's possible something between your computer and server is disallowing the ssh - but since you can ping it and use your torrent application it's less likely.